SWIG Perl interface yields undefined symbol
I have some C code that I'm trying to access from Perl. Just a few very simple calls, an initialize ml_init(int), a call to send it a binary array, a call to act on it, and call to close. This is on an rPi (Linux), and I've used swig to build the intermediate files.
The wrapper file is being made as a .cpp file, and it's resulting .o file is included in the link line.
Everything seems to compile and link just fine, but when I run my test perl app, I get undefined symbol: _Z7ml_initi.  I have used nm on the resulting .so file, and ml_init is listed with a hex value and a T.  However, the type-safe mangled name (which is what is coming up in the error), is also listed, but it has a U in front of it.  The man page for nm states this means the symbol is "undefined".
HUH?
If it's there, in the file, that means it's defined, right? How can it be present, yet not defined to the linker?

Why are you using .cpp?  Perl uses C, and the name that's missing is a C++-encoded version of ml_init.  Compile the wrapper as C code (in a .c file) and you should be OK (or, at least, you're more likely to be OK).

Why do you add C language tag if you use C++ for your code?

Thanks for the responses guys!  My code is strictly in C, however SWIG chose to build the wrapper in C++.  I thought the mangled name looked like a C++ type-safe linkage issue - does anyone know how to tell SWIG to use C, not C++?

I've gotten through this finally, yay!
I have been building by modifying the Makefile.PL and using make and make install.  I no longer remember exactly how I created the original _wrap.cxx file, it most certainly would have been via swig.
Regardless, I simply did a swig -perl on the existing .i file, and this time it created a .c wrapper.  I hacked the Makefile to replace the .cxx extension with .c, and we're now past the Perl error, we're getting into the C code.
